# why is button not taking style in my case MobileButtonResponsive class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

why is button not taking MobileButtonResponsive class ??

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary float-lg-end mb-2  MobileButtonResponsive" href="javascript:confirmMsgSubmit('@string.Format(msg, wordInfo["Menu"])')">@modeName

### js function

function confirmMsgSubmitAction(actionURL, msg) {
document.getElementById("ovly_btn2").onclick = new Function("func_submitAction('" + actionURL"')");
document.getElementById("form_ovly_msg").innerHTML = msg;
dispOvly("ovly");
return;
}

@@media (max-width: 576px) {

```
        .MobileButtonResponsive {
           
            padding: 8px;
            display: flex ;
            justify-content: center ;
            align-items: center ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
.MobileButtonResponsive {
       
        padding: 8px;
        display: flex ;
        justify-content: center ;
        align-items: center ;
    }
}
```